# I have deployed React project on firebase but its didn't showing my website. Its show welcome page

Tags: reactjs, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

How can I get rid of it? This is my firebase.json file

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "amazon",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```